# Cant figure out where to fix IF statement error

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

im trying to fix this this ampscript error. I get a message saying

> Error An IF statement is not closed with the required ENDIF statement.

Can anyone take a look at this script to see what i'm might be missing? (edited to show the remaining code)

```
%%[
set @rows = LookupOrderedRows("Consult_Notifications_Daily_followedreply",3,"date desc","EmailAddress",emailaddr)
set @rowCount = rowcount(@rows)
if @rowcount > 1 then
    set @row = row(@rows,@i)
    set @followedReplyNotificationType = field(@row,"NotificationType")
    set @followedReplyPostName = field(@row,"Postname_1")
    set @followedReplyTargetURL = field(@row,"targeturl_1")
    set @followedReplyRecipientName = field(@row,"RecipientNameDeg")
    set @followedReplyMentionedUser = field(@row,"MENTIONEDUSER")
    set @followedReplyActorName = field(@row,"ActorNameDeg")
    set @followedReplyUser = field(@row,"User")
    set @followedReplyPostTitle = field(@row,"PostTitle_1")
    set @followedReplyUserAccountUrl = field(@row,"UserAccountUrl")
    set @followedReplyActorAccountUrl = field(@row,"ActorAccountUrl_1")
    set @followedReplyThreadUrl = field(@row,"ThreadUrl_1")
    set @followedReplyDate = field(@row,"Date")
    set @followedReplyPostBody = field(@row,"PostBody_1")



endif 

 if @followedReplyNotificationType == 'FollowedReply' then

]%%

    -->
    <tr>
      <td style="padding: 7px 0 0 0;">
        <table width="560" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" borde="0" class="container">
          <tr>
            <td align="center" valign="middle" style="padding:2px 2px 3px 1px; box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.09);" bgcolor="#dfdfdf">
              <table width="558" class="container" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="#ffffff">
                <tr>
                  <td style="padding:20px 20px 20px 20px; font-size: 14px;" align="left">
                    <table width="508" class="container" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="#ffffff">
                      <tr>
                        <td width="508" style="padding: 0 0px 0 0;" class="container" colspan="1" valign="top">
                          <table width="508" class="container" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                            <tr>
                              <td align="left" style="font-size: 18px;font-family: 'Roboto Condensed','Helvetica',Arial,sans-serif; font-weight: none; padding:0 0 10px 0; line-height: normal;">
                                <a href="%%=redirectTo(@followedReplyTargetURL)=%%" style="font-size: 18px;color: #000000;text-decoration:none;font-family: 'Roboto Condensed','Helvetica',Arial,sans-serif; font-weight: none; padding:0 0 10px 0; line-height: normal;">%%=v(@followedReplyPostName)=%%</a>
                              </td>
                            </tr>
                            %%[if not empty(@followedReplyPostBody) then]%%
                            <tr>
                              <td align="left" style="font-size: 14px;font-family: 'Roboto Condensed','Helvetica',Arial,sans-serif; font-weight: none; padding:0 0 10px 0; line-height: normal; color: #606060;">
                                %%=v(@followedReplyPostBody)=%% .. 
                                <a href="%%=redirectTo(@followedReplyTargetURL)=%%" target="_blank" style="font-size: 14px;font-family: 'Proxima Nova','Helvetica',Arial,sans-serif; font-weight: normal; text-decoration: none; color: #007cb0;">read more</a>
                              </td>
                            </tr>
                            %%[endif]%%
                            <tr>
                              <td align="left" style="padding: 0px 0 0px 0; font-size: 14px;font-family: 'Proxima Nova','Helvetica',Arial,sans-serif; color: #3a3b3c;">
                                <a href="%%=redirectTo(@followedReplyActorAccountUrl)=%%" target="_blank" style="font-size: 14px;font-family: 'Proxima Nova','Helvetica',Arial,sans-serif; font-weight: normal; text-decoration: none; color: #007cb0;">%%=v(@followedReplyRecipientName)=%%</a> responded to your post on %%=v(@followedReplyDate)=%%.
                              </td>
                            </tr>
                          </table>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <!-- End Content -->
    <tr>
      <td align="center" class="mobile-pad-top-20" style="padding: 22px 0 0 0; font-size: 16px;font-family: 'Proxima Nova','Helvetica',Arial,sans-serif; font-weight: none; color: #3a3b3c; line-height: normal;">
        <a href="%%=redirectTo(@followedReplyUserAccountUrl)=%%" target="_blank" style="font-size: 16px;font-family: 'Proxima Nova','Helvetica',Arial,sans-serif; font-weight: normal; text-decoration: none; color: #007cb0;">
          See all your posts
        </a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</td>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably have bits of html after your initial ampscript block, and you need to check further down the code, if a closing `ENDIF` exists. Hence you code should be something along these lines:

```
%%[
set @rows = LookupOrderedRows("Consult_Notifications_Daily_followedreply",3,"date desc","EmailAddress",emailaddr)
...
 if @followedReplyNotificationType == 'FollowedReply' then
]%%

<p>Hello world</p>

%%[
endif
]%%
```

This is this final `ENDIF` I suspect is missing altogether.